# Is the description for components of 条 correct?

Tags: simplified-characters, character-identification

During studying 条 character in one of the dictionaries I have found decomposition of this character to two components:

- 夂 zhǐ: to go
- 木 mù: tree; wood (Kangxi radical 75)

I see the 夂 component but I am not sure of 木. Should it not be 小 or something similar instead to 木? When I've enlarged the font it resembles 小 without the horizontal stroke.

Comment: Even after the form changing process, it still resembles 小 *with* a horizontal stroke. Why do you say it's without a horizontal stroke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

条's radical is 木. That's an established fact. Just consult any Chinese dictionary. It's derived from 条's old form (旧字形), which lacks the tick.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the tick" when you say the traditional form would not have the tick. Could you include a form of the character with and without the tick? I found the simplified version, 条, and the traditional version, 條, but the traditional form has more strokes, not fewer.

Comment: He said old = 旧字形, not traditional = 繁体字. Here's a [link](http://chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?submitButton1=Etymology&characterInput=%E6%9D%A1) with some older forms and a character analysis. [This](http://chineseetymology.org/CharacterImages/Lst/L30000/l32100/L32146.gif) one is particularly clear.

Comment: I was partially wrong. I removed the part about the tick not being present in texts from regions outside mainland China. My memory played a trick on me there.

Comment: Looks like it's not present in Japanese use of the character (same Unicode code point, different fonts, so I can only give a [link](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E6%9D%A1) )

Comment: Hmm... I just looked it up on Wiktionary http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9D%A1 and it seems that my original speculation was correct. It might also have to do with the font used. I will have to confirm with someone who uses the Traditional Chinese script natively.

Comment: Maybe you could edit in some pictures or something?

Comment: The government of mainland China is now considering changing the 木 with tick to that without tick as the standard writing. Seems that the public is unhappy with this change...

Comment: @user58955 Do you have sources for that? That would be interesting.

Comment: for instance, see http://www.china.com.cn/culture/txt/2009-08/26/content_18402109.htm and http://culture.people.com.cn/GB/22219/9902864.html

Answer (score 1):

That decomposition is incorrect.

「条」is shorthand for「條」(Pinyin: **tiáo**, [Baxter-Sagart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)) [Old Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese): **/*[l]ˤiw/**, **/*lˤiw/**), which is composed of phonetic「攸」(Pinyin: **yōu**, Baxter-Sagart Old Chinese: **/*liw/**) and semantic「木」(*wood*).「木」sometimes looks like「ホ」when written on the bottom of characters; exact shapes vary between the standards of different regions.

The appearance of「夂」is a writing convention;「夂」doesn't contribute any semantic or phonetic function in「条」. At most, it can be seen as an abbreviation of「攸」.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be 木, 条 means 'twig' originally